# a SPAN within A (HREF)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a span with a function to display a DIV on ONCLICK, but it is within the A (HREF), that clicking, performs the function, and soon after go the site A (HREF), has no way to click on SPAN, perform function, and not go to the page of the A (HREF) ?

```
<a class="style" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
    <span onclick="javascript:display('div1');">\/</span>
    Stack Overflow
</a>
```

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use some jQuery magic here.

```
<a class="style" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
    <span id="inner-button">\/</span>
    Stack Overflow
</a>
```

With js:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'inner-button') {
      // Display div.

      e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what happens is that you're dealing with [event bubbling](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing). Basically when you click on the span, you trigger the onClick event, and it runs. But because the span is inside an anchor tag, you'll also trigger the onClick event of the anchor:

1. You click on span
2. The span click event code runs
3. The span click code finishes, so the event "bubbles" up the chain to the parent container
4. the parent container(anchor tag) activates, so you run that click event (open the page of the href)

To stop this, there's a useful function called `preventDefault`, which will stop the bubbling.

in a javascript file

```
var onClick=function(event){
        //do your code stuff here
        display('div1');
        //then stop the bubbling
        event.preventDefault(); //anchor event won't trigger!
}
```

then in your HTML:

```
<span onclick="onClick(event)">\/</span>
```